# How to do arithmetic in buckets with nested data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a concept I want to write a query for in Elasticsearch, but I can't figure out how from the documentation.

Suppose I have documents in an index that look like this, with nested "owners". (I'm omitting the quotation marks to ease my typing)

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    cost: 8.50,
    owners: [
      { ownerId: 11, share: 0.45 },
      { ownerId: 12, share: 0.55 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cost: 12.00,
    owners: [
      { ownerId: 11, share: 1.0 }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I'd like an aggregation that will multiply cost by the owner's share and bucket it by owner ID, then sum them up.  So if I only had those two documents shown above, I'd get a aggregation with a bucket for ownerId 11 with a cost sum of 15.825 and one for ownerId 12 with a cost sum of 4.675.  It seems like I can do this, but how?

Comment: Is your `owners` field of `nested` type in your mapping?

Comment: Yes, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to store the owner's computed cost at indexing time inside the nested documents? With ES, you shouldn't be afraid of pre-computing as much as you can in order to ease things at searching/aggregation time.

Comment: How then would I get the sum for a large result set for a given ownerId?  I guess I still need to bucket then find the right bucket in my code.  I'm going to go give it a try.

Comment: Yes, but then you can let ES do the maths and simply use a nested `terms` aggregation, no need to mess with scripts which will make your aggregation a real performance hogger.

Comment: OK, I can set aside the arithmetic part and focus on the nested aggregation.  Trying it now.